# Doubt in the solution of a competition combinatorial problem concerning the average number of times the letters of a sequence change

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I am currently going through  Andreescu's 102 combinatorial problems. I couldn't solve number 28 after repeated attempts, so I checked the solution. The problem and solution go as follows:
[image]
However, I do not understand why summing the $N_i$'s and dividing over $20!$ is the average. As I see it, if $S_i$ denotes the number of rows with $i$ boy-girl or girl-boy appearances in the row, the average should be

$\dfrac{\sum_{i=2}^{13}iS_i}{\binom{20}{7}}$.

I was hoping that someone would throw some light on why my formula is incorrect and the logic behind the solution (I am relatively new to combinatorial problems in competitions.)

Comment: See the 2nd answer that I posted, which uses the strategy that you began.

Comment: See the 3rd answer that I posted, which represents a hybrid of Stars and Bars theory and Linearity of Expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both of my previous answers are so long-winded, I am adding a 3rd answer as a separate response.  This answer represents a **hybrid** approach that combines Stars and Bars theory with Linearity of Expectation.  This response has some similarities and some difference to both my (other) Stars and Bars answer, and the official solution given in the original posting.

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

For a discussion of Linearity of Expectation, including a proof that Linearity of Expectation holds when it is applied to dependent events, see [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).

When the $7$ boys are placed anywhere in the row of $20$ positions, they create $8$ regions.  One region before the first boy (on the left), and then one region after each of the boys.

Consider the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 = 13.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

As expected, the number of solutions is

$\displaystyle \binom{13 + [8-1]}{8-1} = \binom{20}{7}.$

Let $P$ denote the probability that in any of the $~\displaystyle \binom{20}{7}~$ solutions chosen at random, the variable $~x_4~$ is $~\geq 1.$

$P$ may be calculated as follows:

Consider the revised equation:

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 = 13.$
- $x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, ~~~~x_1, x_2, x_3, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Settng $y_4 = x_4 - 1,$ the revised equation **bijects** to :

- $y_4 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = (13 - 1) = 12.$
- $y_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~~~~x_1, x_2, x_3, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, the revised equation has 
$\displaystyle \binom{12 + [8-1]}{8-1} = \binom{19}{7} ~$ solutions.

Therefore, the probability that a random solution has $x_4 \geq 1$ can be computed as

$$P = \frac{\binom{19}{7}}{\binom{20}{7}} = \frac{13}{20}.$$

Further, by reasons of symmetry, the same computation of $P$ applies to any of the other variables.  Thus, for $i \in \{1,2,3,\cdots,8\}$, the probability that a random solution to

$x_1 + \cdots + x_8 = 13 ~: ~x_1, \cdots, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$

will have $x_i \geq 1$ is $~\displaystyle P = \frac{13}{20}.$

An occurrence of [G:Boy-1] will occur if and only if $x_1 \geq 1.$

An occurrence of [Boy-7:G] will occur if and only if $x_8 \geq 1.$

For $i \in \{2,3,\cdots,7\}$

- an occurrence of [Boy-(i-1):G] occurs 
  if and only if
- $x_i \geq 1, ~$ which occurs 
  if and only if
- an occurrence of [G:Boy-i] occurs.

Therefore, by Linearity of Expectation, the expected **combined** number of occurrences of [GB] or [BG] is

$$[1 \times P] + [6 \times 2 \times P] + [1 \times P]$$

$$= 14 \times P = 14 \times \frac{13}{20} = \frac{182}{20} = 9.1.$$

Comment: I really enjoyed  all of your answers, any advice on becoming better in combinatorics?

Comment: @Victor The only way that I know of is to find the right class or book on Combinatorics, open it to page 1, and attack.  Amazon reviews are helpful in guessing whether a book is right for you.  So are MathSE questions tagged *book-recommendations* or *reference-request*.  However, a book might be best for someone else, but not best for you.  Generally, since most of the learning takes place in the book's **problems**, you want a book with many, many problems.

Answer (score 2):

> I was hoping that someone would throw some light on why my formula is incorrect and the logic behind the solution

Your approach, **which I discuss in the Addendum**, focuses on the expected number of rows with $i$ [BG or GB] appearances.

The offered solution takes a totally different approach.  Instead, the offered solution examines each of the $(20)!$ possible seatings, and determines how many of these seatings have [BG or GB] **starting in position** $i$.

---

A simpler problem will allow you to visualize the distinction.

Suppose that you were going to examine the $10000$ $4$-digit numbers, where each number was zero-filled on the left, and the numbers ranged from $0000$ through $9999.$

You might then ask, in these $10000$ numbers, how many times does the digit $1$ appear?  You then have two choices for attacking the problem:

- You can ask: how many of the $10000$ numbers will have $k$ $1$'s, where $k$ is some element in $0,1,2,3,4$?  This corresponds to the approach that you are taking.
- You can ask: how many occurrences of the digit $1$ will occur in the leftmost digit?  Assume that this computation is $d_1$.  Then, you can ask the same question for the number of occurrences in the digit $1$ in the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th positions from the left.  If you denote these computations as $d_2, d_3, d_4,$ respectively, then the (overall) desired computation is $d_1 + d_2 + d_3 + d_4$.

The 2nd approach above corresponds to the method taken in the given solution.  One **key difference** in the original problem, and the sample problem above, is that an occurrence of a $1$ in (for example) the leftmost digit is an **independent event** compared to the occurrence of a $1$ in one of the other positions.

In the original problem, the analogous events are **not independent**.  That is, if there is a BG beginning in position 1, this affects whether there is a GB beginning in position 2, because one of the B's has been **already used**.

However, if you examine [this linearity of expectation article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/), you will find a proof that linearity of expectation holds even when the events are not independent.

---

**Addendum**

> As I see it, if $S_i$ denotes the number of rows with $i$ boy-girl or girl-boy appearances in the row, the average should be

> $\dfrac{\sum_{i=2}^{13}iS_i}{\binom{20}{7}}$.

Your approach is valid, but **incomplete**.  Your denominator of $~\displaystyle \binom{20}{7}~$ reflects the number of ways that the $7$ boys could be seated.

If you index each of these seatings, as $~\displaystyle A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n ~: ~n = \binom{20}{7},~$ and you left $f(k)$ denote the number of [BG or GB] occurrences in seating number $A_k$, then you can compute the average number of [BG or GB]
occurrences as

$$\frac{\large\sum_{k=1}^\binom{20}{7} f(k)}{\binom{20}{7}}.$$

Your approach, which is also valid, is similar.

In your approach, you would cycle through each of

$$~f(1), f(2), \cdots, f(n) ~: ~n = \binom{20}{7}~$$ and determine how many of these values were equal to $i$, for $i$ equal to some value in $\{1,2,\cdots,14\}$.  If you let $S_i$ determine how many of the $\displaystyle ~\binom{20}{7}~$ seatings have $i$ occurrences, then you can compute the average as

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{14} iS_i}{\binom{20}{7}}.$$

There are however, two defects in your approach:

- For some reason, you chose to have the summation go from $2$ through $13$, rather than $1$ through $14$.
- You gave no analysis of how you might **analytically** compute $S_i$.  It may be argued that the solution provided was given because the computation's analysis is so elegant.  This leaves open the question: how would you pursue your approach?

Comment: In the beginning, when you start by taking the example of 4-digit numbers, you say that the desired number would be $d_1  + d_2 + d_3 + d_4$, but, wouldn't you be overcounting? because, for example, 1100 has digit 1 in places 1 and 2

Comment: @Victor The example of 4-digit numbers was offered only as a way to help you illustrate the difference between your approach (which can be validly completed, as one of my other answers demonstrates) and the approach taken in the official solution.  You have **mis-read** my example problem: "... in these 10000 numbers, how many times does the digit 1 appear?" : In the number $1000$, the digit $1$ occurs once, and in the number $1100$, the digit $1$ occurs twice.  So, you should attach a **weight** of $(1)$ to the number $1000$ and a **weight** of $(2)$ to the number $1100$.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is helpful to reduce the problem to smaller numbers so that it can be calculated manually. Here we take $5$ instead of $20$ persons and consider a group of two boys and three girls.
\begin{align*}
\{B_1,B_2,G_1,G_2,G_3\}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
In order to analyse the situation it is sufficient to consider the
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{5}{2}=10}
\end{align*}
different rows
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{l|c}
B\quad B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\quad G\quad G&1\\
B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\quad G&3\\
B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\quad G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\color{blue}{\bullet} G&3\\
B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\quad G\quad G\color{blue}{\bullet} B&2\\
G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\quad B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\quad G&2\\
G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\color{blue}{\bullet} G&4\\
G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\quad G\color{blue}{\bullet} B&3\\
G\quad G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\quad B\color{blue}{\bullet} G&2\\
G\quad G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\color{blue}{\bullet} G\color{blue}{\bullet} B&3\\
G\quad G\quad G\color{blue}{\bullet} B\quad B&1
\end{array}
\end{align*}
Each of these rows represents the $2!\cdot 3!=12$ pairwise different configurations when we use the elements from (1) giving a total of $12\cdot 10=5!$ rows. But this is not so important, as we can only focus on $BG$ and $GB$ combinations which are marked with $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ dots.

**One approach:**

We get the multiplicities from the right-most column of the table above and derive according to OPs approach
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1\cdot S_1+2\cdot S_2 + 3\cdot S_3+4\cdot S_4}{\binom{5}{2}}}=\frac{1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+4\cdot 1}{10}
\color{blue}{=2,4}
\end{align*}

**Another approach:**

We focus on the combinations $BG$ and $GB$ for each of the four position pairs $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)$.

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
B&G&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&B&G&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&B&G&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&B&G\\
G&B&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&G&B&\cdot&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&G&B&\cdot\\
\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&G&B\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
We fix a specific position $j, 1\leq j\leq 4$ and let's say the combination $BG$. We calculate the probability of the event that $BG$ occurs at a specific position $j$ by dividing the *favorable number* of possibilities by the *total number* which is as we have two boys and three girls:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{2\cdot 3}{5\cdot 4}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
We note that (2) is strongly related with $N_j$ from OPs problem, since we can (2) write as
\begin{align*}
\frac{2\cdot 3}{5\cdot 4}=\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 3!}{5\cdot 4\cdot 3!}=\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 3!}{5!}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Doubling (3) since we have to respect $BG$ as well as $GB$ at a specific position and using the linearity of expectation we calculate according to (2) and (3)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{N_1+N_2+N_3+N_4}{5!}}=4\cdot \frac{2 (2\cdot 3) 3!}{5!}=4\cdot\frac{ 2(2\cdot 3)}{5\cdot 4}\color{blue}{=2,4}
\end{align*}
and both results coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Posting alternative approach as a separate (long-winded) answer, for clarity.  This approach represents the approach started by the OP (i.e. original poster), in his posting.

The problem can actually be conquered by Stars and Bars theory.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The $7$ boys, placed anywhere in the row of $20$ places, create $8$ regions.  Consider the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 = 13$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.

$x_1$ represents the number of girls before the first boy.  Then, $x_2, \cdots, x_8$ represent the number of girls after each of the boys.

As expected, Stars and Bars theory gives the number of solutions as 
$~\displaystyle \binom{13 + [8-1]}{8-1} = \binom{20}{7}.$

I am going to start with a **flawed premise** and work the problem based on this premise.  Then, I will diagnose and remedy the flaw.

Take any variable $~x_i ~: ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots, 8\}$.

If $x_i > 0$, then there is an BG occurrence  that begins with boy-$(i-1)$ and there is also a GB occurrence that ends with boy-$i$.  So, each solution where $x_i \neq 0$ adds $2$ to the [BG, GB] count.

So, of the $~\displaystyle \binom{20}{7}~$ solutions, you have to enumerate how many such solutions have $r$ of the variables $x_1, \cdots, x_8$ greater than $0,~$ where $r \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,8\}$.  For each such solution with $r$ variables $~\geq 1$, you have to attach a weight of $(2\times r)$ to such a solution.

The flaw is that if $x_1 \geq 1,$ that only adds $1$ to the count of [GB, BG].  The same holds for $x_8$.  I will start by **ignoring** the flaw, and reach a **first-draft** of the enumeration.

Then, I will re-consider the flaw, and finalize the enumeration.

---

Consider the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = 13 ~: ~r \in \{1,2\cdots,8\}$.  
  Note that if $~r = 0,~$ since this corresponds to each of $~x_1, \cdots, x_8~$ equaling $0$, you can't have any solutions when $~r = 0.$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_r \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{r}~$ ways of selecting which $r$ of the $8$ variables will be $\geq 1$.  The presumption is that for whichever $r$ variables are chosen, the other $8-r$ variables will be forced to be equal to $0$.

Then, for any such solution, you can employ the change of variables: $~y_i = x_i - 1 ~: i \in \{1,2,\cdots,r\}$.  So, the revised problem **bijects** to

$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_r = (13 - r) ~: ~y_1, \cdots, y_r \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory, this has 
$\displaystyle \binom{[13 - r] + [r-1]}{r-1} = \binom{12}{r-1}$ solutions.

---

**Note**
I sanity-checked that 
$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^8 \left[\binom{12}{r-1} \times \binom{8}{r}\right] = \binom{20}{7}.$

See also the **Addendum**.

---

So, under the **flawed** premise, each solution with exactly $r$ of the variables being non-zero will add $(2 \times r)$ to the count.

So, the **flawed** total count is

$$\sum_{r=1}^8 \left[(2r) \times \binom{12}{r-1} \times \binom{8}{r}\right]. \tag1 $$

Taking the expression in (1) as a starting point, to remedy the **flaw** in my premise, I now have to identify three categories of solutions:

- Those with $x_1 \geq 1,$ and $x_8 = 0.$
  For each such solution, I have to deduct $1$, since having $x_1 \geq 1$ only adds $1$ to the [GB, BG] count.
- Those with $x_1 = 0$ and $x_8 \geq 1$. 
  By symmetry, the number of solutions here and the corresponding remedy will be identical to the previous bullet-point.
- Those with $x_1 \geq 1$ and $x_8 \geq 1$.  Here, I have to deduct $2$ from each solution.

---

Consider

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 + 0 = 13$.
- $x_1 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, x_2, \cdots,x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Setting $y_1 = x_1 - 1$, the above equation bijects to

- $y_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 + 0 = (13 - 1) = 12.$
- $y_1, x_2, \cdots, x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

This has $~\displaystyle \binom{12 + 6}{6} = \binom{18}{6}~$ solutions.  So, the first adjustment, which (also) covers $x_1 = 0, x_8 \geq 1$ is

$$(-2) \times \binom{18}{6}.$$

The last adjustment is very similar.  Consider

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 + x_8 = 13$.
- $x_1,x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, x_2, \cdots,x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Setting $y_1 = x_1 - 1, ~y_8 = x_8 - 1$, the above equation bijects to

- $y_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_7 + y_8 = (13 - 2) = 11.$
- $y_1, y_8, x_2, \cdots, x_7 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

This has $~\displaystyle \binom{11 + 7}{7} = \binom{18}{7}~$ solutions.  So, the last adjustment is

$$(-2) \times \binom{18}{7}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

The average number of [GB, BG] occurrences will be

$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{20}{7},$$

where

$$N = \left\{ ~\sum_{r=1}^8 \left[(2r) \times \binom{12}{r-1} \times \binom{8}{r}\right] ~\right\} - 
\left\{ ~2 \times ~\left[\binom{18}{6} + \binom{18}{7} ~\right] ~\right\} \tag2 $$

$$= 806208 - 2\left[18564 + 31824\right] = 705432.$$

Then,

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{705432}{77520} = 9.1.$$

This (convoluted) approach agrees with the given solution.

---

**Addendum**

For what it's worth, I just realized that the equation below can be demonstrated analytically.

> $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^8 \left[\binom{12}{r-1} \times \binom{8}{r}\right] = \binom{20}{7}.$

Re-indexing, the equation becomes:

$\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^7 \left[\binom{12}{r} \times \binom{8}{r+1}\right] = \binom{20}{7}.$

Since $~(r+1) + (7-r) = 8,~$ you have that:
$\displaystyle \binom{8}{r+1} = \binom{8}{7 - r}.$

So, the assertion becomes

$\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^7 \left[\binom{12}{r} \times \binom{8}{7-r}\right] = \binom{20}{7}.$

This assertion is merely a special case of the more general assertion:

- $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^d \left[\binom{a}{r} \times \binom{b}{d-r}\right] = \binom{a+b}{d}.$
- $a,b,d \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~d \leq \min(a,b).$

This assertion is proven via set theory.  
Let $S = \{1,2,\cdots,a\}.$ 
Let $T = \{a+1, a+2, \cdots, a+b\}.$ 
Let $U = S \cup T.$

The number of ways of selecting $d$ items from $U$, sampling without replacement is $~\displaystyle \binom{a+b}{d}.$

For each such selection of $d$ items, there will have to be exactly $r$ items from $S$ and $(d - r)$ items from $T$, where $r$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,d\}.$

The number of ways of selecting $r$ items from $S$ and $(d-r)$ items from $T$, sampling without replacement is $\displaystyle \binom{a}{r} \times \binom{b}{d-r}.$

Therefore,

$$ \sum_{r=0}^d \left[\binom{a}{r} \times \binom{b}{d-r}\right] = \binom{a+b}{d}.$$